# How to find the limit of $x_n$ if $x_1=1; x_{n+1}=2+\frac {3}{x_n}+\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to find the limit of $x_n$ if $x_1=1; x_{n+1}=2+\frac {3}{x_n}+\frac{1}{n}$.

My idea is to limit $x_n$ from both sides with something, and prove that these sequences' limits are the same.

So, I can say that:
$y_{n+1} = 2 + \frac {3}{x_n} \leq 2+\frac {3}{x_n}+\frac{1}{n} = x_{n+1}$. Аnd its limit is 3.

But I cannot find any sequence $z_n$ whose values ​​satisfy the inequality $x_n \leq z_n$ and $\lim { z_n } = 3$.

Can someone help me with this task, please. Maybe exist any other solution of this task. I have no more ideas so that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Set up a double sided inequality to bound $x_{n+1}$ for $n$ large enough. This can be proved via induction.

> $ 3 < x_n < 3 + \frac{1}{n-1}$.

Hence conclude that $\lim x_n = 3 $.

Comment: Works for $n\ge 4$.

Comment: @lhf The idea is that you could use different double sided inequalities then the one I listed (which seems the most intuitive).

Comment: If you change $1\over n-1$ to $3\over n-1$, the inequality kicks in right away, at $n=2$ (with a $\le$ instead of a $\lt$), and the induction is nice and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

If you can show the sequence is bounded (below, as Calvin's hint suggests) and eventually monotonic (decreasing), then let $L$ be the limit of the sequence, so that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2+\frac3{x_n}+\frac1n\right)\implies L=2+\frac3L$$

Then solve for $L$.

Comment: From empirical observation, the sequence is monotonically decreasing only after $ n \geq 6$. It's not immediately obvious to me why that's true, or how we could prove it directly.

Comment: I tried proving monotonicity, but failed as this is not as straightforward as you seem to claim. The problem is that $x_{n+1}-x_n<0\implies (x_n-3)n>\frac {x_n}{x_n+1}$ RHS is bounded, but $x_n-3$ is very small and apparently gives monotonocity for bigger and bigger $n$ ! So we have to proove that $x_n-3$ is sublinear... not an easy task compared to Calvin's option.

Comment: I made no claims of it being easy to prove, but *if* it could be proved, then this method could be used. I had not tried to prove it myself.